# Power Query Group By Another Table Criteria

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a report in excel. I want to get a final output base on the info at the Main Table and Criteria Table.

**Main Table** - This table has many column and is already in Power Query known as **Proposal**

```
| Vendor   | Business   Area | Amount |
|----------|-----------------|--------|
| 11000010 | MY01            | 100    |
| 11000017 | MY51            | 200    |
| 11000018 | MY53            | 150    |
| 11000019 | MY55            | 220    |
| 11000030 | MY57            | 214    |
| 11000045 | MY59            | 500    |
| 11000056 | MY5HA           | 586    |
| 31000125 | MYHW            | 564    |
| 31000133 | MY71            | 546    |
| 31000139 | MY73            | 4896   |
| 31000144 | MY38            | 486    |
| 31013425 | MYSA            | 4869   |
| 81000225 | MYSA            | 489    |
```

**Criteria Table**- This table is already in Power Query known as **VendorCriteria**.

If Business Area is Blank but the Vendor fall within the range, will still fall under respective grouping.

```
| Vendor Low Range | Vendor Upper Range | Business Area                                                     | Group  |
|------------------|--------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|--------|
| 10000000         | 29999999           | MY51,MY53,MY55,MY57,MY59,MY5HA,MYHW,MY71,MY73,MY75,MYSA,MYSW,MYS1 | Group1 |
| 10000000         | 29999999           | MY01,MY38                                                         | Group2 |
| 60000000         | 69999999           |                                                                   | Group3 |
| 30000000         | 39999999           |                                                                   | Group4 |
| 80000000         | 89999999           |                                                                   | Group5 |
```

**Result**- This is just to show respective line result base on criterial table.

```
| Vendor   | Business   Area | Amount | Base on Criterial Table |
|----------|-----------------|--------|-------------------------|
| 11000010 | MY01            | 100    | Group2                  |
| 11000010 | MY51            | 200    | Group1                  |
| 11000018 | MY53            | 150    | Group1                  |
| 11000019 | MY55            | 220    | Group1                  |
| 11000030 | MY38            | 214    | Group2                  |
| 11000045 | MY59            | 500    | Group1                  |
| 11000056 | MY5HA           | 586    | Group1                  |
| 31000125 | MYHW            | 564    | Group4                  |
| 31000133 | MY71            | 546    | Group4                  |
| 31000139 | MY73            | 4896   | Group4                  |
| 31000144 | MY38            | 486    | Group4                  |
| 31013425 | MYSA            | 4869   | Group4                  |
| 81000225 | MY38            | 489    | Group5                  |
```

**Final Output**- This is the end result I want.

```
| Group  |
|--------|
| Group1 |
| Group2 |
| Group4 |
| Group5 |
```

I did try to group by vendor by using below code and invoke it at my **Main Table**, but then I am stuck at the Business Area. 
What I really wish is all the code could be variable (base on the Criteria Table), because below code I need to hardcode the range.

```
let ValBucket =
    {
        {(Vendor)=>Vendor<29999999, "Group1"},
        {(Vendor)=>Vendor<69999999, "Group2"},
        {(Vendor)=>Vendor<89999999, "Group3"}
    },
    Result = List.First(List.Select(ValBucket, each _{0}(vals))){1}
in
Result
```

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.

**Main** and **Vendor Criteria** are the names of the queries with those tables in them as you stated:

**Main**
[image]

**Vendor Criteria**
[image]

*Please read the comments in the code to better understand the algorithm*

***M Code: Edited:** to account for differences in sample data vs real data*

- Remove extra column in criteria table
- Cells which contained *null space* (`""`) in sample were *`null`* in real data

  - replaced *null* with `""`
- Real data has duplicate vendors with one or more `Business Areas` not present in the list of Business Areas in the criteria table.

  - Changed algorithm to select Group
  - You'll need to check if this will always be producing correct results.

```
let
    critTbl = VendorCriteria,

//Remove unneeded column
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(critTbl,{"Column1"}),

//replace *null*  with a null string, else Text.Split in next step will fail
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns1",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Business Area"}),

//change Business Area into a List
    criteria = Table.Buffer(Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value", {"Business Area", each Text.Split(_,",")})),

//Get the Main table
    main = Proposal2,

//add column of filtered criteria tables where the filter depends on the values in 
//   "Vendor Low Range"  and "Vendor Upper Range"
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(main, "Custom", 
        each Table.SelectRows(criteria, (t)=> 
            [Vendor]>= t[#"Vendor Low Range"] and [Vendor] <= t[#"Vendor Upper Range"])),
    //Determine which Group
//if there are multiple matches, pick the first Group
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Group", each 
        let 
            x=Table.SelectRows([Custom], (t)=>
                List.Contains(t[Business Area],[Business Area])),
            y=if Table.RowCount(x) = 1 then x[Group]{0} else [Custom][Group]{0}
        in 
            y,
            type text),


    //Remove just the Custom (table) column to display "Result"
    Result= Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1","Custom"),

//Remove the other columns except "Group" to be able to produce the Sorted Distinct table of Groups
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Result,{"Vendor", "Business Area"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Final Output" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"Group", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Final Output"
```

***Result step***
[image]

***Final Output***
[image]

Comment: Hi @Ron Rosenfeld thank you for your prompt solution. Everything works fine except the last code 
```#"Final Output" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"Group", Order.Ascending}})```

It gives this error 
```Expression.Error: There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation.
Details:
    [List]```
When I click "Go To Error" it leads to this code
```#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(main, "Custom", 
        each Table.SelectRows(criteria, (t)=> 
            [Vendor]>= t[#"Vendor Low Range"] and [Vendor] <= t[#"Vendor Upper Range"]))```

Comment: @Junekuan  so the previous steps show without an error? Probably some difference between your actual data and the sample that you posted that is not taken into account by the code.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pz1YXqz6LYGNbzaj1GLywc_Bgx8IpL1y/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106709183291368552893&rtpof=true&sd=true) of the sample file. I tried few method, but still couldn't overcome the problem.

Comment: @Junekuan The major problem is that your actual data, unlike your sample data, has duplicate Vendors where one or more of the Business areas is not present in your criteria table.  Therefor the formula for adding the "Group" column will fail.  I will look at the best fix for that later today.

Comment: @Junekuan See the edited code. Check to ensure it is always assigning the correct Group

Comment: It works. Thank you so much on helping out in this.